# Flutter :The named parameter 'textAlign' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, parameters, scaffold

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawer: Drawer(),
    body: Text(
      "Home page ,Omar OS ",
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          color: Colors.red,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
No named parameter with the name 'textAlign'.
lib/main.dart:30
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1470:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scaffold({
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textAlign` parameter belongs to the `Text` widget but you've defined it on `Scaffold`. This should work:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawer: Drawer(),
    body: Text(
      "Home page ,Omar OS ",
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          color: Colors.red,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, another example here: https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-textalign-property-explained/

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Home extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          drawer: Drawer(),
          body: Text(
            "Home page ,Omar OS ",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.red,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          );
          
    }
  }
```